# import excel file to database with enum data type - gettin stuck

Tags: php, mysql, enums

this is a small php quiz im making...I am trying to upload tables rows into my database through excel sheet. But I am getting stuck at how to  handle the enum type. 
Like in my table i have given enum type (0,1) for"correct" answers. 
And in my excel sheet if the correct answers are options 2,4 i.e., "1" and 1,3 should be "0" in table. How do I do this? Can anybody suggest any quick solution?

My code and table:

```
    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into gf(answer, correct) values('$data[0]','$data[1]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form
}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='uploady.php' method='post'>";

    print "File name to import:<br />\n";

    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help I think :

```
$correct = ($data[1]==2 or $data[1]==4)? 1 : 0;
$import="INSERT into gf (answer, correct) values('$data[0]','$correct')";
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This worked. In my excel sheet, if my "correct" field has value like 2,4 and next value 1,3 for correct answers. How do I make this store as 1 and rest options as 0??? Do I have to use some string function?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but the statement in the parentheses is your condition and the value after the question mark is the code that will happen if your condition is true and the other one is for false.
btw if this answer helps, please accept it for future references.